# Error in placing data in a string array

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

```
 void readit(FILE* filePtr, int* num1, int* num2, char** strings, int lines)
     {
int t;
char line[50];

for (t = 0; t < lines; t++){
    fgets(line, 50, filePtr);
    *(strings + t) = strtok(line, " "));
    *(num2 + t) = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    *(num2 + t) = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
}
```

In this code, the *strings portion is not performing as intended. Every pass through the code overwrites the entire string array. The fgets is reading in the correct data, and every loop through if I print the value of the first token, it is what I expect. Outside of the loop, (or inside if i print (i - 1) all the arrays *str + 1, *str + 2 etc.. Will contain the value of the last pass through.

For example.

```
         *(strings + 0) = "Hi";
         printf("%s", *(strings + 0)); //Will print hi

         //next iteration
         *(strings + 1) = "You";
         printf("%s", *(strings + 1)); // will print you
         printf("%s", *(strings + 0)); // will print you as well
```

Comment: No, I am getting a name from a file. The example just demonstrates the behavior of the string array.

Comment: I think `strings[0]` and `strings[1]` would look more natural.

Comment: I don't think we're going to find the problem by looking at the program all piecemeal. Why don't you post the complete program?

Comment: Okay.... that doesn't help.

Comment: this is the problem. its a very large program.

Comment: The parts you're showing aren't large. Just wrap `int main(){` `}` around it and make the problem stand-alone. It's a valuable exercise.

Comment: I have narrowed it down to this point, I could write main and call this function.. but it isn't necessary. The function updates the array in main if I do it outside this loop with hard coded values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you only have one string buffer that is constantly being over-written.  Remember `strtok` does not allocate new memory it returns a pointer into the buffer it is passed.  Each time through the loop `strtok` sets `*(strings + t) = line`.  Then in the next loop you over-write the date in `line`.  What you are ending up with is an array of  char pointers all pointing to the same string buffer.  (You are also returning a pointer to a local variable, which is undefined behavior)

You code is equivalent to to the following:

```
    char *strings[2];
    char line[50];
    strcpy(line, "Hi");
    *(strings + 0) = line;
     printf("%s", *(strings + 0)); //Will print hi

     //next iteration
     strcpy(line, "You");
     *(strings + 1) = line;
     printf("%s", *(strings + 1)); // will print you
     printf("%s", *(strings + 0)); // will print you as well
```

So both `strings+0` and `string+1` point `line` so of course over-writing line with change what `strings+0` prints.

You either need to allocate memory dynamically or base in a buffer that you can `strcpy` into.  For example:

```
char strings[5][50];
readit(filtPtr, &num1, &num2, strings, 50);

...

void readit(FILE* filePtr, int* num1, int* num2, char** strings, int lines)
{
     int t;
     char line[50];

    for (t = 0; t < lines; t++){
        fgets(line, 50, filePtr);
        strcpy(*(strings + t), strtok(line, " ")));
        *(num2 + t) = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
        *(num2 + t) = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
    }
}
```

Comment: So the numbers still work because each type I am converting a pointer into an int that is saved?

Comment: And essentially, strtok returns a ptr and so I just kept assigning that same ptr to my char*'s?